# WPF crashes if no access to a parent folder

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a simple C# Application using WPF to display the computer name and IP information. If it is run on the local computer it works fine. If it is run from a network location that has full access throughout, it works fine. But if you run it in a folder that is in another folder that you do not have access to it will crash.

For instance
I have servershare `\\main\department1\sharefolder`
I can open and read `\\main`
I cannot open `\\main\department1` directly
But i can navigate to `\\main\department1\sharefolder`

If I run it on `\\main` It works fine.
If I run it in `\\main\department1\sharefolder` it crashes.

I really want it to work in this location. I have full access to this folder. Is there something in WPF that is making this happen? Should I use a different language?
And there is nothing in the code trying to read its folder location

Comment: Where does it crash? What is the exception? What does your code look like? Have your tried to use in a WinForms app?

Comment: The gist of the program is, open a window with 2 boxes that say "Please Wait" and the program will update those text fields with the computername and the IP. I rewrote it in VB and instead of getting an error, the program simply does nothing. The box pops up and it just says please wait. This only occurs if it is run from the share.

Comment: I am just starting with programming and I believe I should be using WPF instead of winforms. Not totally sure, but I will try in winforms and see what that gets me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure sufficient access is granted explicitly on `\\main\department1\sharefolder` it might be inheriting 'denies' from its parent.

Being able to navigate to the folder might not be enough. 
You probably need more access than that (write, execute, ...)

**on second thought **

my guess is that you are running into a permission issue on a .net level. You are running the application from a network drive/share; applications run like this have less permissions and reading environment variables and such could be restricted. Show us the code, catch exceptions and read about full and partial trust applications.

Comment: I have checked that I have added my username with explicit access to "Full Control". When drilling down to the full list of permissions I have them all checked.

Comment: @ryan - I added to my answer